# cUrl: post with a mixture of text source and file source

Tags: post, curl

Using cUrl in Linux or Unix, I can post with data source either from text input or from file. For example:

```
curl -v -k -X POST --data-urlencode data1=abc some/url
curl -v -k -X POST --data-urlencode data2@path/to/file some/url
```

But is it possible to post both at the same time? If yes, how?

(To me it looks like just mixing

```
data1=abc&data2@path/to/file
```

does not work. But it could be my machine's problem. Anyone knows how?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after minutes I posted this question I came up with one solution, though it may seem kind of verbose:

```
curl -v -k -X POST --data-urlencode data1=abc --data-urlencode data2@path/to/file some/url
```

It is just adding one more segment of --data-urlencode but it works.

Please let me know if you have better solutions. Thanks!